# Placing of the three elements

Tags: html, css, menu

I have this css style and html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <body>
            <header class="header">
                <div id="header-wrapper">
                    <div id="box-left">
                        <div id="top-menu-left"></div>
                        <nav class="menu-left">
                            <ul id="main-nav">
                                <li><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://themify.me">Themify</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://icondock.com">IconDock</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://ndesign-studio.com">N.Design</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div id="box-right">
                        <div id="top-menu-right"></div>
                        <nav class="menu-right">
                            <ul id="main-nav">
                                <li><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://themify.me">Themify</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://icondock.com">IconDock</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://ndesign-studio.com">N.Design</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="content-wrapper">
                <div id="content" class="clearfix">
                        <h2 align="center">Sielsko Anielsko</h2>
W przeciwieństwie do rozpowszechnionych opinii, Lorem Ipsum nie jest tylko przypadkowym tekstem. Ma ono korzenie w klasycznej łacińskiej literaturze z 45 roku przed Chrystusem, czyli ponad 2000 lat temu! Richard McClintock, wykładowca łaciny na uniwersytecie Hampden-Sydney w Virginii, przyjrzał się uważniej jednemu z najbardziej niejasnych słów w Lorem Ipsum – consectetur – i po wielu poszukiwaniach odnalazł niezaprzeczalne źródło: Lorem Ipsum pochodzi z fragmentów (1.10.32 i 1.10.33) „de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum”, czyli „O granicy dobra i zła”, napisanej właśnie w 45 p.n.e. przez Cycerona. Jest to bardzo popularna w czasach renesansu rozprawa na temat etyki. Pierwszy wiersz Lorem Ipsum, „Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...” pochodzi właśnie z sekcji 1.10.32.</div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #261501;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

#header-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

#box-left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 42%;
    float: left;
}

#top-menu-left {
    height: 155px;
    width: 450px;
}

#box-right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 42%;
    float: left;
}

#top-menu-right {
    height: 155px;
    width: 450px;
}

.logo {
    height: 250px;
/*  width: 300px;*/
    width: 16%;
    float: left;
    background:#ffffff url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow:  0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#site-logo {
}

/* navigation */

.menu-left {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}

.menu-right {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}

#main-nav ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#main-nav li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#main-nav li a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav li a.active, #main-nav a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #D9CD60;
}
```

The problem is that the right menu slightly overlaps the central element where the logo, any change of margins or z-index does not give the desired effect or made ​​a mistake somewhere and I can not find the cause.

jsfiddle: [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/guzior/s3snc/7/)

I found a fix after posting my question but I'm not sure is it correct way. Now another little problem with menu position I need to left and right menu put closer to the logo. The jsfiddle looks good, but on local copy menu go down

//last edit

footer positioning in terms of wrapper and content
when i set footer to stay on bottom it's being hidden by content, i want to set footer to stick to the bottom of the page

**EDIT**

fixed the placement of content but the footer is now above

```
#content {
    padding-top: 380px;
}

#tresc {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1180px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

fixed the footer problem

//edit

have someone an idea how to make those menu to fit mobile devices ?

Comment: post your markup aswell

Comment: We need also HTML code and even better would be a jsfiddle example.

Comment: I can't notice the problem in your fiddle. Everything looks fine. Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage space between menus and logo do the following:

1. remove `float:left` from all three elements.
2. add `display: inline-block` to all three elements.
3. make sure that parent element (`#header-wrapper`) has `text-align: center`

Then by changing `margin` property of the `.logo` you can separate it from the menus.

However there is one small problem with `display: inline-block`. It will create small gaps between logo and the menus which in your case will cause the right menu to break into new line. To fix it, make sure there are no *white-spaces* between opening and closing tags of these three elements, like this:

```
(...)
</div><div class="logo">
```

instead of this

```
(...)
    </div><!-- here is a newline and a tab which both are white-spaces -->
    <div class="logo">
```

**EDIT**:

According to your last update about footer,
You set `.wrapper` height to `100%` which means it takes all the height of the window. Then your `.bg` div has height set to `500px`. So if browser window is less than `500px` plus `200px` of the header, the footer gets *eaten* by the wrapper. I can't explain precisely why this happens but to fix this problem all you have to do is put the footer inside the wrapper.
Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3snc/8/.

Also, to avoid further problems you should put header inside the wrapper. If wrapper is meant to be `height: 100%` (combined with `body, html { height: 100% }`) it **must** be the immediate and the **only** child of the body.

Comment: tried but I stay at the solution of the current, can you look at actual jsfiddle for footer position?

Comment: There is no footer in your fiddle. Can you update it to show me how you approched it?

Comment: after adding more text in content div , the footer is hidden

Comment: I got it, finally! Your `#content` div is positioned relatively and has `top: 380px`. Remove this property and change `margin` value to `380px auto 0`

Comment: yes but then the bg image is also with 380px top margin, i need to have this image under the header like earlier

Comment: Then change it to padding.

Comment: changed to padding didn't help even margin doesn't fix , the content need to be lowered for 380px to begin from almost end of bg image

Comment: any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/s3snc/9/. I changed some things in CSS and the markup. header, content and footer are all wrapped in wrapper. Also the padding (380px) is added to `.bg`, not `#content` plus some minor changes.

Comment: the image must be cutted to 500px, i think i will edit the image to cut it

Comment: the footer is still behind content div, content div needs to start about 60px before the end of bg image, changed one thing http://jsfiddle.net/guzior/s3snc/10/ but if still put more text footer stays behind

Comment: i'm stuck on footer, no idea how to position it to stay on bottom and don't go behind contet div.